# Loading variables from external file on server into HTML doc?

Tags: javascript, html, variables

The title really says it all, but I'd like to have a file with many strings in  a folder with my .html file, and somehow load them into the page, perhaps with document.write() or something like that. The website follows one template, and I need to have many string files to interchangeably load into the document, as I imagine a social network does with it's profile page. For example:

```
"My name is $NAME. I'm %AGE years old. I'm %HEIGHT inches tall." % ('Files/strings.txt')
```

with the file laid out like this:

```
$NAME = 'Bob'
$AGE = '20'
$HEIGHT = '70'
```

or

```
Bob
20
70
```

or even

```
Bob.20.70
```

Any way I can do this would be nice, though I don't particularly enjoy AJAX. There is no data transfered from the client, so it seems I shouldn't need AJAX.

Comment: Normally this is done by the server...

Comment: Is a server-sided language is an option?

Comment: @JeffreySweeney what do you mean? Like a CSS file, I just want to load data into an HTML page on the server, from the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use only javascript and no ajax:

```
// strings.js
var data = {
 NAME: 'Bob',
 AGE: 20,
 HEIGHT: 70
};
```

---

```
// index.html
<script src="strings.js"></script>
<script>
  window.onload = function () {
    var tags = document.getElementsByClassName('templated');
    for (var i=0; i<tags.length; ++i) {
      applyTemplate(tags[i]);
    }
  }
  function applyTemplate (tag) {
    for (var key in data) {
      var regexp = new RegExp('%'+key, 'g');
      tag.innerHTML = tag.innerHTML.replace(regexp, data[key]);
    }
  }
</script>

<div class="templated">
  "My name is %NAME. I'm %AGE years old. I'm %HEIGHT inches tall."
</div>
<p>
  "My name is %NAME. I'm %AGE years old. I'm %HEIGHT inches tall."
</p>
```

in the above example, the paragraph won't be converted, but the div will

But if you can use PHP:
if you can use php then:

```
//strings.txt:
$data['any_namespace'] = array(
  'name' => 'Bob'
  'age' => 20
  'height' => 70
);
```

---

```
//index.php:
<?php
  require_once 'strings.txt';
  echo <<<HTML_CONTENT
My name is $data['name']. I'm $data['age'] years old. I'm $data['height'] inches tall.
HTML_CONTENT;
?>
```

---

Hope this is what you wanted :)

Comment: Perfect! Could I use `<div class="templated" id="somecss>`?

Comment: you can use any combination , that is just an example I gave :). Or disregard the ID/classes altogether and just do:       applyTemplate(document.documentElement) which will do a global replace on your whole HTML

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it could be done with a basic templating engine. Have a look at [Dust.js](http://akdubya.github.com/dustjs/) or other [JavaScript templating engines](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=javascript%20templating&aq=f&sugexp=chrome,mod=5&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Dust has the benefit of being able to use pre-compiled templates stored in .js files. Not sure if any others also have this ability, I'd assume some do...

Answer (score 0):

If it, s Static file. You should store your data using a JSON structure within a. json file.